# PHP DocuSign: How to format the signer custom email body?

Tags: php, laravel, email, docusignapi

I've setup a separate email subject and email body for each signer pragmatically like below and it's working fine.
$pdEmailBody contains plain text as it doesn't take HTML formatting.

Now when recipient getting the email, the email body is not formatted right. Every paragraph has automatic 'indent' (please see the picture).

I would like to know how I format the email body so that all text will be left align and no indent.

[image]

```
$signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
                'email' => $pdEmail, 
                'name' => $pdName,
                "recepient_id" => "1",
                'routing_order' => "1",
                'email_notification' => new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientEmailNotification([
                    'email_subject' => $pdEmailSub,
                    'email_body' => $pdEmailBody
                ])
            ]);
```

Comment: What is the value of $pdEmailBody ?

Comment: The indent is not coming from DocuSign, check the value of $pdEmailBody

Comment: The value of $pdEmailBody is plain text like:

$pdEmailBody = 'Hello '.$pdName.',
Kindly review the linked course-section '. $courseSection.' - '. $courseTitle.' to be instructed.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and I'm not seeing this. You need to use `"\n\r"` in your string to specify a new line.
You probably are using some other string that includes these tabs or other marks that create this. Please check the string (end string, not the one with variables, the actual value) that is passed to `email_body` and confirm.

Comment: thanks a lot. I checked the string and separate the lines with "\n\r" and it seems to solve the indent issue.